# How can I combine the Index in the python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

in the following, can I make a single index for all the entries with common index.

```
cric = pd.Series(['India', 'Pakistan', 'South Africa', 'England', 'New Zealand'], 
                 index = ['Cricket', 'Cricket', 'Cricket', 'Cricket', 'Cricket'])
ftbl = pd.Series(['England', 'South Africa', 'Australia', 'Netherlands', 'New Zealand'], 
                 index = ['Football', 'Football', 'Football', 'Football' , 'Football'])
hock = pd.Series(['India', 'Pakistan', 'South Korea', 'England', 'India', 'New Zealand'], 
                 index = ['Hockey', 'Hockey', 'Hockey', 'Hockey', 'Hockey', 'Hockey'])

all_countries_1 = cric.append(ftbl)
all_countries_1 = all_countries_1.append(ftbl)
all_countries_1 = all_countries_1.append(hock)
all_countries_1 = all_countries_1.to_frame()
all_countries_1.columns = ['Countries']
all_countries_1
```

[image: Actual Data]

I want the following as my out
[image: The Expected Output]

Comment: What do you mean by "single index" `all_countries_1.groupby(level=0)['Countries'].apply(list)`?

Comment: No, I mean that for a single Index Value, such as Cricket, all countries that play cricket appear. something like For [index=Cricket] => [Countries = India, Pakistan, Australia, ]etc.

Comment: Please provide an expected output for your sample data

Comment: Expected output added, please note that CR means Cricket, and FT means football etc.
I want only 3 (multirow) index values and not single index value for each country that play cricket for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
# zip the first three chars of the index and the index together
z = list(zip(all_countries_1.index.str[:3], all_countries_1.index))
# create multi index
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(z)
# assign index
all_countries_1.index = idx

                 Countries
Cri Cricket          India
    Cricket       Pakistan
    Cricket   South Africa
    Cricket        England
    Cricket    New Zealand
Foo Football       England
    Football  South Africa
    Football     Australia
    Football   Netherlands
    Football   New Zealand
    Football       England
    Football  South Africa
    Football     Australia
    Football   Netherlands
    Football   New Zealand
Hoc Hockey           India
    Hockey        Pakistan
    Hockey     South Korea
    Hockey         England
    Hockey           India
    Hockey     New Zealand
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit about the what is going on? It solves my problem, but I also need to understand to learn more. Thanks :) Also, I may use your solution in my future blog but I will cite your solution.

Comment: actually got it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If, by single index, you mean an index made of autoincrementing numbers, there is nothing special you have to do. That is the default index for a DataFrame, so using the `reset_index()` method will get what you want. The next step will probably be to rename your index column. You can chain that method with `reset_index` and take care of it one line.

```
all_countries_1 = all_countries_1.reset_index().rename(columns={"index":"Sports"})
```

Comment: No, I mean that for a single Index Value, such as Cricket, all countries that play cricket appear. something like For [index=Cricket] => [Countries = India, Pakistan, Australia, ]etc.